# How to use Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana via API inputs?

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-7

I am really newbie on this ELK stack and I need some help.

I have a scenario where I need to set and run using docker-compose those 3 fellows, apart from needing help in everything I would like to know if there is a way to make inputs on Elasticsearch or on Logstash via API.

I mean, I have my java app producing data/logs and I would like to know if I could call an endpoint to input those data and see them on Kibana.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: this book https://www.amazon.com/Spring-5-0-Microservices-Scalable-Reactive-ebook/dp/B01N3YVPJH  chapter 8.

Comment: this seems like a very broad question for this forum. What I recommend is take one or two classes on `udemy` on ELK stack (or any other online courses ). `udemy` is very cheap. Spend time, learn the concepts and ask specific questions here if you still need further assistance.